# Unzip a file and copy the contents to different folder based on condition

Tags: python, bash, shell, find, cut

Folks,

i have a requirement to unzip file and copy the contents of the subdirectories of the unzipped file into different location

For Example:

Filename: temp.zip

unzip temp.zip

we have folder structure like this under temp

```
 temp/usr/data/keanu/*.pdf's
 temp/usr/data/reaves/*.pdf's
```

my requirement is to go to the unzipped folders and copy

```
/keanu *.pdf's to /desti1/
and 
/reaves/*.pdf's to /dest2/
```

i have tried the below:

```
unzip.sh <filename>

filename=$1
unzip $filename
```

//i have stuck here i  need to go to unzip folder and find the path and copy those files to different destination

***UPDATE on My script unzip the file and recursively copy recommended type of files to destination folder without changing the (by preserving the directory structure)***

Filename: unzip.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
#shopt -s nullglob globstar
filename="$1"
var1=$(sed 's/.\{4\}$//' <<< "$filename")
echo $var1
unzip "$filename"
cd "$(dirname "$filename")"/"$var1"/**/includes
#pwd
#use -udm in cpio to overwrite
find . -name '*.pdf' | cpio -pdm /tmp/test/includes
cd -
cd "$(dirname "$filename")"/"$var1"/**/global
#pwd
find . -name '*.pdf' | cpio -pdm /tmp/test/global
```

Comment: choose your weapon: bash or python.

Comment: anything is fine @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the zip is always structured the same:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
filename="$1"
unzip "$filename"
cp "$(dirname "$filename")"/temp/usr/data/keanu/*.pdf /desti1/
cp "$(dirname "$filename")"/temp/usr/data/reaves/*.pdf /desti2/
```

In case the structure changes and you only know that there are directories `keanu/` and `reaves/` somewhere:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob globstar
filename="$1"
unzip "$filename"
cp "$(dirname "$filename")"/**/keanu/*.pdf /desti1/
cp "$(dirname "$filename")"/**/reaves/*.pdf /desti2/
```

Both scripts do what you specified but not more than that. The unzipped files are copied over, that is, the original unzipped files will still lay around after the script terminates.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Socowi

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
import zipfile,os

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("temp.zip")
for f in zf.namelist():
    if not f.endswith("/"):
        dest = "dest1" if os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(f))=="keanu" else "dest2"
        zf.extract(f,path=os.path.join(dest,os.path.basename(f)))
```

- iterate on the contents of the archive
- filter out directories (end with "/")
- if last dirname is `"keanu"`, select destination 1 else the other
- extract directly under the selected destination